# How can I serialize an array of valus instead of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have those two models Article and Tags

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  after_initialize :set_defaults
  belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"
  has_many :article_tags, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :article_tags

  validates :slug, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :title, presence: :true
  validates :body, presence: :true
  validates :description, presence: :true
  validates :favorites_count, presence: :true

  scope :recent, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
end
```

---

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :article_tags, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :articles, through: :article_tags
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

I Create those serializers for each model

```
class ArticleSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :title, :slug, :favorites_count, :description, :body, :favoritesCount
  attribute :updated_at, key: "updatedAt"
  attribute :created_at, key: "createdAt"
  has_many :tags, key: "tagList", serializer: TagSerializer
  has_one :author, serializer: AuthorSerializer

  def favoritesCount
     # To be implemented
     0
  end 
end
```

---

```
class TagSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name
end
```

Here when I call the /articles api it returns like this which is logic since I put name attribute on my tag serializer

[image]

How can I make the tagList field returns an array of values instead of objects so it will be like this
tagList = ['hola','test','react','angular']

I'm using ruby 3.1 and rails 7.0 and ActiveModelSerializer

Any help please??!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code or data. Instead, add it directly into your question as [markdown text formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/421705). You can edit your question by clicking on the **edit** link below it.

Comment: ...because: 1) readers may want to cut-and-paste your code or data, and 2) links have a tendency to eventually break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this line from your `ArticleSerializer`

```
has_many :tags, key: "tagList", serializer: TasSerializer
```

and add the following method to your `ArticleSerializer`

```
def tags
  object.tags.map(&:name)
end
```

and add `tags` to the list of attributes that should be rendered:

```
attribute :tags
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling the ***TagSerializer*** for ***tagList***, you can define a method in ArticleSerializer to return an array of tag names. Like you did for ***favoritesCount***.